# Pandas extractall using a different regular expression for each observation

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing one variable with text and another one with a word that should be searched for in the text.

The word may be different for every observation/text. The str.extractall() function from Pandas can only take one regular expression. But is there a way to use this or another function so that the regular expression can be different for each observation, while still doing it in a parallelized way without the need of manually looping through each observation one-by-one?

Comment: `"|".join(your_word_list)` or `r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(your_word_list))` or `r"(?<!\w)({})(?!\w)".format("|".join([re.escape(x) for x in your_word_list]))` should help.

Comment: This will for each observation match ANY word from my word-list, no? But I need to specify a different regex-pattern for each observation. Is there a way to do this more efficient than looping through each observation and specify the regex-pattern for that observation one-by-one?

Comment: The `word1|word2|wordN` regex searches for either `word1` or `word2`... or `wordN` in each string. If you need to check for each word individually, you might want to use something like `my_cols = [col for col in df.columns if word in col]`  - however, I cannot help more since I don't quite see the problem. Please post the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).